# Prequisite install .Net 3.5 framework on windows 8 with msi built from visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-installer, installation

I have an msi project within Visual Studio 2005 c#.
I have selected the: "Install .Net 2.0" within the prequisite of the msi and selected the option to run the msi from the current location, thus having the .Net installation directory together with the msi instead of downloading it from windows web site, to save the user's time. 
When running this msi on windows 8, I get a message that the app requires >net 2.0 and needs to download .Net 3.5 from the internet.

My question is, how can I add .Net 3.5 using Visual studio 2005 to my prequiste msi? or is there on-the-fly solution, so I can add the .Net 3.5 installation directory together with the msi and let the msi/ or vb script install this directory instead of downloading the .Net from the internet.

Comment: Right, you cannot get .NET 2.0 installed on Windows 8.  You *must* use the bootstrapper you get when you select the .NET 3.5 prerequisite.  Which ensures the Win8 compatible version of .NET 3.5 is deployed.  Which also ensures that programs that target 2.0 will work.  Getting this from a VS2005 setup project could well be a problem.  8 years is a very long time to hang on to dev tools.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass it, lets say with a vb script. So the vbscript will check if it is win8 and without .Net 3.5 and if so, to install .Net 3.5 from local file dotnetfx35.exe, instead of downloading the .Net 3.5?

Comment: No, downloading is required.  You could simply go into Control Panel + Programs and Features + Turn Windows features on and off.  Tick the .NET Framework 3.5 option.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply Hans. Why can't I add the dotnetfx35.exe to the installation disk and write a vbs code to check if it is windows 8 and does not have .Net 3.5 installed. Why do I have to download it from windows web site? Why can't I have it locally on the installation disk?

Comment: Because dotnetfx35.exe won't run on Windows 8.  .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 is handled by the OS in Windows 8.  It's Windows 8 going out to Windows Update that is the download.  dotnetfx35.exe isn't involved.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the easiest "solution" to your problem is compile your assemblies with .NET 2.0 (CLR 2.0) but manifested to allow running on .NET 4.0 / 4.5 (CLR 4.0).

[Running .NET 2 Runtime applications under the .NET 4 Runtime](http://www.davidmoore.info/2010/12/17/running-net-2-runtime-applications-under-the-net-4-runtime/)

Then in your installer, configure the prereq to be skipped in a newer version of .NET is detected.  You'll have to test these scenarios but it should just work.  FWIW it's unlikely that you actually need .NET 2.0/3.5 on Windows 8.  .NET 4.0/4.5 should suffice.